# 'Webpage not available' with WebView.loadData() ONLY in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview, emulation

I'm calling `loadData` on my `WebView` and passing it some HTML in the form of a String like so:

```
webView.loadData( htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8" );
```

It works fine on my Galaxy Tab 10.1, but the `WebView` displays:

`Webpage not available`

when running on the emulator with everything set up to match my Galaxy Tab.  Setting `android.permission.INTERNET` in the manifest has no effect, though I shouldn't need that permission since I'm rendering in-memory HTML, and not accessing anything over the data connection.

What's going on?

Answer (score 34):

Try with this code

```
webView.loadData( URLEncoder.encode(htmlString).replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8" );
```

insted of

```
webView.loadData( htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8" );
```

it should work, because sometimes character like '%', '\', '#' creates problem if its not properly Encoded

Comment: Thanks Viraj, you just saved my life, I was stuck on this prob for a log time. +1 for you (I would give you +100 if I could).

Comment: Your answer helped me, +1 for you :)

Comment: Helped me too, Thanks Viraj. Also stuck on this prob. +1 for you.

Answer (score 28):

In `2.x` platforms `loadData()` fails in some cases (it requires the html to be escaped), use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` instead and pass `null` for `baseUrl` and `historyUrl`:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: this worked for me. and it is probably faster than "using URLEncoder and replaceAll regex".

Comment: +1 for me. Just a quick addendum: you should edit your answer and put `webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: thnx a lot fardjad, i may be your slave for 40 years

Comment: loadDataWithBaseUrl() worked all the time while loadData() produced "Web page errors" sometimes.

Comment: I couldn't upvote this enough... I had no idea why this function was useful until now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually thanks for @Viraj for the answer.

Google currently deprecated the above and you should use this instead:

```
webView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(mAdvertisement.getContent(), "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", " "), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```